# Where was the place where Moses followed al-Khidr and met the boy?

Tags: tafseer, prophet-musa, surat-al-kahf

According to the famous verses at Surat Al Kahf, 60-74:

> And [mention] when Moses said to his servant, "I will not cease [traveling] until I reach the junction of the two seas or continue for a long period."

Until Moses met with Khidr, where they later went on a ship:

> So they set out, until when they had **embarked on the ship**, al-Khidh r tore it open. [Moses] said, "Have you torn it open to drown its people? You have certainly done a grave thing."

Later:

> So they set out, until when they met a boy, al-Khidhr killed him.

**Where did Moses follow al-Khidr?** (or where did they met the boy?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2715):

> (في المقام الأول، طلب موسى من الخضر لأنه نسي وعده، ثم جاء طائر وجلس على حافة القارب، غمس منقاره مرة أو مرتين في البحر، وقال الخضر لموسى: فإن المعرفة ومعرفتك، بالمقارنة بمعرفة الله، هي مثل ما أخذه هذا الطائر من البحر ". ثم نزلوا من القارب، وبينما كانوا يسيرون على الشاطئ، رأى الخضر صبيا يلعب مع فأخذ الخضر رأس الصبي وسحبه بيديه وقتله وقال موسى له: (هل قتلت شخصا بريئا لم يقتل أحدا، فأنت قد ارتكبت شيئا نكر! '' وقال: "لم أكن أقول لكم أنك لن تكون قادرة على الصبر معي '')
>
> (In the first instance, Musa asked Al-Khidr because he had forgotten his promise. Then a bird came and sat on the edge of the boat, dipping its beak once or twice in the sea. Al-Khidr said to Musa, "My knowledge and your knowledge, in comparison to Allah's knowledge, is like what this bird has taken out of the sea.'' Then they both disembarked from the boat, and while they were walking on the shore, Al-Khidr saw a boy playing with other boys. Al-Khidr took hold of the boy's head and pulled it off with his hands, killing him. Musa said to him, ("Have you killed an innocent person who had killed none! Verily, you have committed a thing Nukr!'' He said, "Did I not tell you that you would not be able to have patience with me'')

This is the only thing I could find. They traveled further up the sea and disembarked and went to the **shore** where the boy was. The next bit is that they go to a town.

There is **no evidence in Qu'ran or Sunnah** of where all this took place but it would be around Israel/Palestine as that is where Musa was sent to.

Comment: Thanks! I've read the tafseers about this, didn't find anything either that's why i asked. I guess no one knows the answer to the question, so ill just accept this!

Answer (score 0):

We have only clues:

**1)** Junction of two seas. How appropriate 2 seas and 2 special person. ***Al-Kahf 18:60.***
**2)** Educated guess: the boat traveling short distance. Probably work back and forth on same route carrying ppl. plus the boat owners know Al-Hidr. ***Sahih Bukhari USC-MSA web (English) ref. Vol. 6, Book 60, Hadith 249-251.***
**3)** "*There is no evidence in Qu'ran or Sunnah of where all this took place*". **Yes. Priod.** *"but it would be around Israel/Palestine as that is where Musa was sent to"*. **No**. To me it's clear nobody knows Moses (as). His own ppl certainly would recognize him. Later on (the wall case) nobody even recognize both (evindence is their not welcoming the two). ***Al-Kahf 18:77 + Common sense.***
**4**) Educated guess: the journey didn't take long, probably few days. Prophet Muhammad (saw) said if he had more patience (Moses(as)) we would have known more (i.e. what happened next). ***Sahih al-Bukhari USC-MSA web (English) ref. Vol. 1, Book 3, Hadith 123***

Hope that helps.

Comment: please include sources, citations, or references.

Comment: Citations/references added, you are right about asking these, on religious content, arguments should always backed-up with valid evidences (aka Quran+Sunnah).